# MySQL dynamic key/pairs converted to single record sets

Tags: mysql

I'm sure my question is misleading, so allow me to demonstrate my challenge. I have a table that holds dynamically built data (user sets up field names and allows the entry of particular data)

**Table**

KEY | VALUE | PERSON

---

key1 | value1 | personA 
key2 | value2 | personA 
key3 | value3 | personA 
key1 | value1 | personB 
key2 | value2 | personB 
key3 | value3 | personB

---

I need this to be changed to the following as a query so I can filter a search on these records:

**Dynamically created table for querying**

PERSON | Key1 | Key2 | Key3

---

personA | value1 | value2 | value3 
personB | value1 | value2 | value3

---

Please provide me with a mysql query to produce the following result. NB, the keys are dynamically created by the user and can thus result in many more / less.

Comment: This is called a _pivot_. MySQL doesn't have this capability. You can only do it if you know all the possible key values.

Comment: Why do you need to pivot the data so you can filter it?

Comment: This is much easier done with 3 queries and a few lines of script rather than a single DB query. Sounds like homework or a similar challenge.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments. To be honest I figured this would be the easiest way to filter the data - ie. the user enters a search by typing in a word and adding filter parameters (ie. which field keys he wants to compare the search word to) and the matching records should be returned. I think I'll just script a build function to put together each row to construct the record object.

Comment: Thanks for the Pivot term Barmar.. New to me but now I know

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, the term I was looking for was a Pivot, which is not supported by MySQL. I will therefore pull the single row records into my script and build an object from them before returning the result to the user. Seems to be the easiest way.